# Convert from mysql_query from PHP into Python?

Tags: php, python, mysql, messaging

Is there anyway to convert this line from PHP into python and if so please explain what every thing means and how it works please.

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO chatitems VALUES ( null, null, '".
    mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['user'] ).
    "', '".
    mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['message'] ).
    "')" );
```

I have been having a lot of trouble and tried doing

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='24.44.205.122', user='root', password='1234',
                          database='chat')
x = conn.cursor()

try:
    x.execute("INSERT INTO chatitems VALUES (%s, %s)""", (null, null), conn.escape_string(self.request.get("user")). "', '". conn.escape_string(self.request.get("message")). "')" );
except:
    conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```

If anyone can explain how to do this it would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

If you use [parameter passing style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15), DB API will take care of escape. You don't need to escape yourself and construct sql:

```
x.execute("INSERT INTO chatitems VALUES (null, null,  %s, %s)", [
    self.request.get("user"),
    self.request.get("message")
])
```

> The term bound refers to the process of binding an input value to a
>   database execution buffer. In practical terms, this means that the
>   input value is directly used as a value in the operation. **The client**
>   **should not be required to "escape" the value so that it can be used** —
>   the value should be equal to the actual database value.